# linking shared-object rlibmemcached.bundle failing on gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, memcached

When I try to install the memcached gem:

```
gem install memcached -v '1.4.1
```

I get this error and the install fails:

```
linking shared-object rlibmemcached.bundle
ld: in '/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib', file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rlibmemcached.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Any one have any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this later... 
I should have read the prompt more closely. I had a conflicting libcrypto.dylib on my computer. I ran

```
brew doctor
```

and that highlighted the erroneous files. I removed them, then the gem install went just fine.